# C programming - Strdup not capturing and storing filenames in array correctly

Tags: c, arrays, strdup

I'm trying to store file names in an array. The array is in a struct, and I want to store the names of files found in a directory in the array. However, the process that I'm using to store the names seems to be corrupting 2 or 3 of the names during the process. I think the problem is with the `strdup` keyword. Whenever I run my program either it reads in the program executable (which is in the directory above the directory I'm reading the files from), or weird symbols stored in the first few array locations. The following is part of my program where I'm trying to capture and store the file names, and a picture of the output results:

```
typedef struct{
  char *filename;
}filename;

typedef struct Configs{
  char file_data_path[50];
  char event_log_path[50];
  filename *fn_data;
}Configs;

typedef struct TestConfigs{
  bool done;
  int selection;
  int attempts_counter;
  Configs tConfig;
}TestConfigs;

void read_files(struct TestConfigs *setup);

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello Test\n");
  TestConfigs setup;
  read_files(&setup);
  system("pause");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void read_files(struct TestConfigs *setup)
{
  setup->done = false;
  setup->attempts_counter = 3;

  char cwd[1024];
  DIR *dir = NULL;
  struct dirent *pent = NULL;
  struct stat info;
  int total_num_of_files = 0;

  strcpy(setup->tConfig.file_data_path, "data/");

  chdir(setup->tConfig.frame_data_path);
  if((getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd))) != NULL)
  {
      printf("Current Directory: %s\n", cwd);
  }

  dir = opendir(cwd);

  if(dir != NULL)
  {
     while((pent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
     {
         if(stat(pent->d_name, &info))
         {
             printf("ERROR: stat%s: %s\n", pent->d_name, strerror(errno));
         }
         else
         {
             if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
             {
                 if((strcmp(pent->d_name, ".cproject") == 0) || (strcmp(pent->d_name, ".project") == 0))
                 {
                     continue;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     total_num_of_files++;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     printf("# of files found: %d\n", total_num_of_files);
     rewinddir(dir);

     // SETUP ARRAY HERE!
     setup->tConfig.fn_data = malloc(total_num_of_files);
     total_num_of_files= 0;

     printf("During Storage Process:\n");
     while((pent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
     {
         if(stat(pent->d_name, &info))
         {
             printf("ERROR: stat%s: %s\n", pent->d_name, strerror(errno));
         }
         else
         {
             if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
             {
                 if((strcmp(pent->d_name, ".cproject") == 0) || (strcmp(pent->d_name, ".project") == 0))
                 {
                     continue;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(pent->d_name));
                     setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename = strdup(pent->d_name);  // <- Possible source of the storage problem
                     printf("Filename stored in fn_data[%d] = %s\n", total_num_of_files, setup->Config.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename);
                     total_num_of_files++;
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     printf("\n");
     printf("After Storage Process:\n");
     for(int i = 0; i < total_num_of_files; i++)
     {
         printf("Filename stored in fn_data[%d] = %s\n", i, setup->tConfig.fn_data[i].filename);
     }
  }
  closedir(dir);
}
```

[Output results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVRDk.jpg)

What can I do to resolve the corrupt storage of the filenames in the first few array locations? How come only the first few locations aren't properly storing the filenames, but the other locations are Ok? Is the issue with `strdup`, and if so, what's a good alternative for capturing and storing the file names in the array? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `strdup` works fine, the problem is somewhere in your code. Use your debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setup->tConfig.fn_data = malloc(total_num_of_files);`

One byte per file?

Need, e.g., `setup->tConfig.fn_data = malloc(total_num_of_files * sizeof(filename));`

Comment: I'm trying to allocate space that can hold an array of file names that are `char d_name[260]`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you updated edit. I changed `setup->tConfig.fn_data = malloc(total_num_of_files);` to `setup->tConfig.fn_data = malloc(total_num_of_files * sizeof(filename));` but now the program is crashing. I think the issue is with my array setup.  If I setup my array like `filename fn_data[total_num_of_files]` using just the `typedef struct filename` and not as a nested struct, it works. But as a nested struct, it either crashes or just files the array with `(null)`.

Comment: Thank you @Dipstick. I did your suggestion, and set it equal to `strdup`: `setup->tConfig.fn_data = malloc(total_num_of_files * sizeof(filename)); setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename = strdup(pent->d_name);`.  My program no longer crashes, stores junk, and holds onto the filenames detected and not the program executable. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(pent->d_name));
setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename = strdup(pent->d_name);  // <- Possible source of the storage problem
```

makes no sense; the `strdup()` will overwrite the pointer returned by `malloc()` and that memory will be forever lost ("leaked") which is bad.

You don't have to allocate memory for `strdup()`, it does that for you. It's basically:

```
char * strdup(const char *s)
{
  const size_t sz = strlen(s) + 1;
  char * const p = malloc(sz);
  if (p != NULL)
    memcpy(p, s, sz);
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Just a small note for completeness. `strdup()` may also set `errno = ENOMEM`.

Comment: @unwind I see. I removed the `setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files].filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(pent->d_name));` and just left the 2nd line. But when I run it, it still prints weird characters in the first (3) array slots. Is it the way I'm setting up the array that could be the source of the issue? When I initially changed it to `setup->tConfig.fn_data[total_num_of_files]` I got the warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value].